# Redis advice- when to group data and when to split it up

Tags: caching, data-structures, redis

Hoping to get some sage advice from those that have been in the trenches, and can help me better understand when to keep data clustered together in Redis, and when to split it up.

I am working on a multi-tenant platform that has GPS data coming in every 3-5 seconds for each asset I track. As data is processed, we store additional information associated with the asset (i.e. is it on time, is it late, etc).

Each asset belongs to one or more tenant.  For example, when tracking a family car, that car may exist for the husband, and the wife.  Each needs to know where it is relative to their needs.  For example, the car may be being used by the teenager and is on time for the husband to use it at 3:00 pm, but late for the wife to use it at 2:30 pm.

As an additional requirement, a single tenant may want read access to other tenants.  I.E. the Dad wants to see the family car, and any teenager's cars.  So the heirarchy can start to look something like this:

Super-Tenant --

```
--Super Tenant (Family)
   --Tenant (Dad)
      --Vehicle 1
         --Gps:123.456,15.123
         --Status:OnTime
      --Vehicle 2
         --Gps:123.872,15.563
         --Status:Unused
   --Tenant (Mom)
      --Vehicle 1
         --Gps:123.456,15.123
         --Status:Late
      --Vehicle 2
         --Gps:123.872,15.563
         --Status:Unused
   --Tenant (Teenager)
      --Vehicle 1
         --Gps:123.456,15.123
         --Status:Unused
      --Vehicle 2
         --Gps:123.872,15.563
         --Status:Unused
```

My question has to do with the best way to store this in Redis.

I can store by tenant - I.E. I can use a Key for Dad, then have a collection of all of the vehicles he has access to.  Each time a new GPS location comes in (whether for Vehicle 1 or Vehicle 2), I would update the contents of the collection.  My concern is that if there are dozens of vehicles that we would be updating his collection way to often.

Or

I can store by tenant, then by vehicle.  This means that when Vehicle 1's GSP location comes in I will be updating information across 3 different tenants.  Not to bad.

What gives me pause is that I am working on a website for Dad to see all his vehicles.  That call is going to come in and ask for all Vehicles under the Tenant of Dad.  If I split out the data so it is stored by tenant/vehicle, then I will have to store the fact that Dad has 2 vehicles, then ask Redis for everything in (key1,key2,etc).

If I make it so that everything is stored in a collection under the Dad tenant, then my request to Redis would be much simpler and will be asking for everything under the key Dad.

In reality, each tenant will have between 5-100 vehicles, and we have 100's of tenants.

Based on your experience, what would be your preferred approach (please feel free to offer any not offered here).

Answer (score 0):

From your question it appears you're hoping to store everything you need under one key. Redis doesn't support nested hashes as-is. There are a few recommendations from this [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/98373) on how to work around.

Based on the update cadence of the GPS data, it's best to minimize the total number of writes required. This may increase the number of operations to construct a response on read; however, adding read only slave instances should allow you to scale reads. You can tune your writes with some pipelining of updates.

From what you have described it sounds like the updates are limited to the GPS and status of a vehicle for a user. The data requested on read would be  for a single user view what their set of vehicle position and status is.

I would start with a Tenant stored as a hash with the user's name, and a field referenceing the vehicles and sessions associated to the user. This is not really necessary if you take similar naming conventions, but shown as an option if additional user data needs cached.

```
- Tenant user-1 (Hash)
-- name: Dad (String)
-- vehicles: user-1:vehicles (String) reference to key for set of vehicles assigned.
-- sessions: user-1:sessions (String) reference to key for set of user-vehicle sessions.
```

The lookup of a the vehicles could be done with key formatting if none of the other tenant data is needed. The members would be references to the keys of vehicles.

```
- UserVechicles user-1:vehicles (Set)
-- member: vehicle-1 (String)
```

This would allow lookup of the details for the vehicle. Vehicles would have their position. You could include a field to reference a vehicle centric schedule of sessions similar to the user sessions below. Also you could place a vehicle name or other data if this is also required for response.

```
- Vehicle: vehicle-1 (Hash) 
-- gps: "123.456,15.123" (String)
```

Store the sessions specific to a user in a sorted set. The members would be references to the keys storing session information. The score would be set to a timestamp value allowing range lookups for recent and upcoming sessions for that user.

```
- Schedule user-1:sessions
-- member: user-1:vehicle-1:session-1 (String)
-- score: 1638216000 (Float)
```

Tenant Sessions on a vehicle you could go simply with the listing of the status in a string. An alternative here is shown that would allow storing additional state of scheduled and available times if you need to support vehicle centric views of a schedule. Combining this with a sorted-set of vehicle sessions would round this out.

```
- Session user-1:vehicle-1:session-1 (Hash)
-- status: OnTime (String)
-- scheduled_start: 1638216000 (String) [optional]
-- scheduled_end: 1638216600 (String) [optional]
-- earliest_available: 1638215000 (String) [optional]
```

If you're not tracking state elsewhere you could use a hash to store the counters for the cache objects you have for when it comes time to issue a new one. Read and increment these when adding new cache objects.

```
- Globals: global (Hash)
-- user: 0
-- vehicle: 0
-- session: 0
```

For updates you would have: 200k write operations per update cycle.
100k  tenants-vehicles (1000 tenants * 100 vehicles/tenant) each with

- 1 HSET vehicle
- 1 HSET session

Pipelining and tuning the number of requests in the pipeline can improve write performance, but I would anticipate you should be able to complete all writes in <2s.

For a read you would have something like: ~300 operations per user per request.

- 1 HGETALL user
- 1 ZRANGESTORE tempUSessions user-sessions LIMIT 200 (find up-to 200 sessions in a timeframe for the user)
- 200 HGETALL session
- 1 SMEMBERS user-vehicles (find all vehicles for the user)
- 100 HGET vehicle gps (get vehicle location for all vehicles)

**Considerations:**

A process to periodically remove sessions and their references after they pass would keep the memory from growing unbounded and performance consistent.

Adding some scripts to allow for easier updates to the cache when a new user or vehicle is added and for returning the state you described needing for display to a user would round this out.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Happy to help. Was a fun problem to think through.